# Using a pronoun outside of quotations to refer to a person mentioned in quotations who hasn't been introduced yet

Tags: style, dialogue, quotes

Would the line:

> "Peter!" cried his father.

make grammatical sense? It seems to work intuitively, but I'm just not sure. It's also a tough question to google, as it turns out, so any reply would be much appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Writing.SE *Flirprum*! I formatted your question a bit. For example you need an empty line to make a paragraph (hit Enter twice) or two spaces before hitting Enter once to get a soft linebreak. There is a little help bar at the top of the box where you write and you can view the results below that box. You can also click on "edit" to check out other posts and how they did something. If you have a moment please take the [tour] and visit the [help] to learn more about the site. Have fun!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does the reader already know the father?

I'm not certain that matters, but i assume we do. In either case - Yes. You are introducing a character through another character.

This type of character introduction is similar to style #2 at [the link](https://www.nownovel.com/blog/how-to-introduce-characters/).

The link provides an example of this type of introduction from Joseph Conrad's *Heart of Darkness.*

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely. It had been done before, and maybe more often than we think.

```
“‎TOM!"
No answer.
"TOM!"
No answer.
"What's gone with that boy, I wonder? You TOM!"
No answer.
```

(c) Mark Twain

Comment: This isn’t really an example of what OP asked.